# Ipad with apple pencil write anywhere, not writing anywhere

Tags: ipad, apple-pencil, handwriting, ios

## A new iPad iOS14 and an Apple pencil

I hare recently acquired an iPad from work. In has iOS 14 and an apple pencil.

I iOS 14 says that I can use the pencil as a keyboard (text input device) anywhere. I tried the demo / training app. It seems OK.

## I then tried it in a real situation.

The first thing that I tried was a google doc (we use them at work. Don't ask why we are using google on iPad). I get the pen icon appear and the little tool tray. However the pen acts as a finger and causes the page to scroll up and down.

It seems to work in some form boxes, in some apps, including the document/file rename form of google docs.

**How do I get it to work in the main part of google docs. So that I can write a document with it?**
It seems that the problem is that the start of the first line has to be in the input box for the handwriting recognition software to be triggered, and in this situation it is not happening. If possible I would like to be able to write anywhere (on the screen), and for it to write at the current cursor position. And for there to be cursor positioning tools.

Is this possible?

Comment: I cannot get it to work in any useful way on either the Web nor App.  Other than Insert Drawing and that is remarkably tedious.  Google will need to add support for the Apple Pencil by implementing the iPadOS APIs for the Pencil.  Click Help then Submit feedback to Google.

Comment: @JamesBrickley So apple did not do the obvious and implement the text entry API (as would be used by a keyboard). But still claim write anywhere.